# Java Setting Coordinates

Tags: java, coordinates

I have a question here and i can't get my code to work. I would appreciate some help because i tried my best.
The questions a bit long so i apologize in advance!

**Question:** Design a class named MyPoint to represent a point with x and y-coordinates. the class contains the following:

-the data fields x and y that represent the coordinates with get methods

-a no-arg constructor that creates a point(0,0)

-a construction that constructs a point with specified coordinates

-two get methods for the data fields x and y, respectively

-a method named distance that returns the distance from this point to another

-a method named distance that returns the distance from this point with specified x0 and y-coordinates.

```
class Point
{
  private final double x;
  private final double y;

  public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public double getX() { return(this.x); }
  public double getY() { return(this.y); }

  public double distance(Point that) {
    return( this.distance(that.getX(), that.getY() ) );
  }

  public double distance(double x2, double y2) {
    // square root( ((x1-x2)^2) + ((y1-y2)^2) )

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Point(10D, 10D).distance(new Point(0D,0D)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Look at `Math.sqrt` and `Math.pow`.

Comment: What problem are you having with your code? Are you unsure how to do a square root or power of 2 calculation? By the way, `return` is not a function, so you can just use e.g. `return this.x;`.

Comment: Why not just extend from Point? `class MyPoint extends Point {}` Unless of course this is a homework question and not anything realistic, in which case you need to be much more specific about what your actual problem is.

Comment: That is not a question.  That is a list of requirements.  What is your question?

Comment: uhhm. sorry guys im new to this. Question would be like, what am i missing to make everything work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the Math class methods you are looking for: `Math.sqrt()` and `Math.pow()`.

```
public double distance(double x2, double y2) {
    return Math.sqrt((Math.pow((this.x - x2), 2) + Math.pow((this.y - y2), 2)));
}
```

And you forgot the empty constructor

```
public Point(){
    this.x=0;
    this.y=0;
}
```

One last advice: If you are not absolutely sure that you will never change `x` and `y` then don't make them `final`. Just in case you want to use this class again and maybe change `x` and `y` somehow.

Comment: It is a good practice to let *immutability* manifest itself in final variables. So the recommendation should be: Make every field `final` unless you *have* to make it non-final. And BTW: `Math.pow(dx,2)` is *very* inefficient compared to `dx*dx` (may not be so important here, but ... you know, some people still think that *Java* is inefficient, and in many cases, it's not *Java*, but the *code* ;-))

Comment: @Marco13: you are of course right, `Math.pow` is a little bit exaggerated when a simple `dx*dx` would suffice :) As for the `final` I was trying to say, that as long as the code is still in development it might be rather ..a pain.. than helpful to declare variables as final. When everything is finished, it makes sense to do that – and good IDEs should detect `final`izable variables automatically and propose that to you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to wrap the expression with brackets

```
 public double getX() { return(this.x); }
 public double getY() { return(this.y); }
```

this is fine

```
 public double getX() { return this.x; }
 public double getY() { return this.y; }
```

And you miss the default constructor with no param.

To call another constructor in constructor, you just call `this(args)`

For the distance look at [Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class and functions sqrt(double a) and pow(double a, double b)